How can I define linked types (e.g., abstract matrix and corresponding column type)?
I am writing functions manipulating binary matrices and I would like to make them parametric where possible.
How can I create structs that have, for example, a matrix and an element of the column space of the matrix?
Two representative types I am thinking of are Matrix{Bool} and the following struct that encodes a sparse matrix by having the set of nonzero indices for each column
mutable struct SparseBinaryMatrix <: AbstractSparseMatrix{Bool,Int64}
    shape::Tuple{Int64,Int64}
    cols::Vector{Set{Int64}}
    SparseBinaryMatrix(cols::Vector{Set{Int64}}) = minimum(map(minimum, cols)) < 1 ? error("Specified an index less than 1.") : new((maximum(map(maximum, cols)), length(cols)), cols)
end

Base.size(A::SparseBinaryMatrix) = A.shape
Base.getindex(A::SparseBinaryMatrix, i, j) = i in A.cols[j] #TODO: add bounds check
Base.setindex!(A::SparseBinaryMatrix, v::Bool, i, j) = v ? push!(A.cols[j], i) : delete!(A.cols[j], i)
Base.eachcol(A::SparseBinaryMatrix) = A.cols

I want to have a struct that holds a matrix and an element of the column space, but the only way I can think of implementing it is to allow the matrix and the vectors to have independent types and manually limit them in constructors, e.g.,
struct Example{T, U}
    matrix::T
    vector::U
end

Example(matrix::SparseBinaryMatrix) = Example{SparseBinaryMatrix, Set{Int64}}(matrix, eachcol(matrix)[1]))
Example(matrix::Matrix{Bool}) = Example{Matrix{Bool}, Vector{Bool}}(matrix, eachcol(matrix)[1])

This works, but is a lot of boiler plate code. Is there a better way to do this?

Can you describe how SparseMatrixCSC{Bool,Int64} fails to meet your needs?

@PaSTE that is another type I would like to be able to handle and consider switching to after profiling. I am doing a lot of Gaussian elimination-style operations which, at least in other languages, tends to be rather slow in CSC because deleting from or inserting into columns requires shifting all subsequent entries and so is O(n), while in the above it is O(1). I also find the above to be intuitive for what I need :)

And just to head it off: I am aware that Gaussian elimination is not a good alternative to A \ B. In my case, the matrix is the check matrix of a binary linear code and I am specifically researching methods to minimize the weight of each check operator, i.e., the number of entries in each column
